# How can I import my database (articles and tags) into blogger?

Tags: xml, import, blogger

Is there are minimal XML specification which can be used to import blog using Import blog feature?

Answer (score 0):

BlogML is the standard for this.

You can find specifics here http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97416